# Java - RegEx matcher: how to show all results and prevent losing information

Tags: java, regex

so I am working on a project in JAVA and I am struggling with regular expressions.

I am trying to **simplify** my problem, cause otherwise it would be too complex: 
 I have String (**simplified: a list of animals like "Animal 1: Rabbit Dragon Turtle Animal 2: Horse Dolphin Animal 3: Bambi Animal 4: lion cat dog Animal 5: beast"**). 
 What I now want are String results, which contain the animals, like **for example a field [Rabbit Dragon Turtle, Horse Dolphin, Bambi, lion cat dog, beast]**. In my problem I don't know the names of the animals, I **just know the structure of the String**, which is "Animal 1: XXX Animal 2: XXX ..." while XXX could be a String longer than just one word.

So what I tried is:

```
String animals = "Animal 1: Rabbit Dragon Turtle Animal 2: Horse Animal 3: Bambi Animal 4: lion Animal 5: beast"

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Animal (\\d)(.*?)Animal (\\d)"); //that's what I am searching for
Matcher mat = pat.mat(animals);

while(matcher.find()) { 
     System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

And my problem is now, that my output looks like 
*"Animal 1: Rabbit Dragon Turtle Animal 2"*
*"Animal 3: Bambi Animal 4"*
which means, that I am loosing the "Animal 2: Horse Dolphin Animal 3" part and so on...

So perhaps you could help me and tell me, how I can prevent losing information. 
 I read some Tutorials and found out, that if the matcher matches with a pattern, the matcher is **"jumping" to the rest of the string** and is not searching for another result beginning in the first result.

It would be very kind of you, if you could help me, cause if I could solve this problem, I just have to delete the "Animal 1", "Animal 2", "Animal 3" ... and I will get my results :)

Sorry also, if my English is bad, I am not native (German here). 
Thank you very much in advance! 
Kind regards 
Basti

---

UPDATE *** After geting 2 very good answers, which were very helpful, but still didn't solve my problem, I realised, that I simplified my problem too much. So I try it with that: My "real" problem: 

My String is *"<w:t>task 1</w:t> **XXX** <w:t>task 2</w:t> **XXX** <w:t>task 3</w:t> **XXX** <w:t>task 4</w:t>"* which is an XML String made out of a word document. Now **I have to find all the XXX** which is written between the <w:t>task n</w:t> and <w:t>task n+1</w:t>.

Comment: The update has **completely** different pattern than that in the initial question which was pretty focused and got completely blurred afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex, `Animal \d+: \w+(?=( Animal \d+:)?)` which means `Animal \d+: \w+` **followed by** optional `( Animal \d+:)`.

**Followed By** is specified by `?=` i.e. [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and optional is specified by a `?` at the end of the optional characters.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String animals = "Animal 1: Rabbit Animal 2: Horse Animal 3: Bambi Animal 4: lion Animal 5: beast";

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Animal \\d+: \\w+(?=( Animal \\d+:)?)");
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(animals);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Animal 1: Rabbit
Animal 2: Horse
Animal 3: Bambi
Animal 4: lion
Animal 5: beast
```

If you do not want `Animal \d+:`  caption before the name of the animal, an easy solution is to split the string on `Animal\\s+\\d+:\\s+` which means `Animal`followed by one or more whitespace characters followed by one or more digits followed by `:` followed by one or more whitespace characters.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String animals = "Animal 1: Rabbit Dragon Turtle Animal 2: Horse Animal 3: Bambi Animal 4: lion Animal 5: beast";
        String[] arr = animals.split("Animal\\s+\\d+:\\s+");

        for (String s : arr) {
            if (!(s.isBlank() || s.isEmpty()))
                System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Rabbit Dragon Turtle 
Horse 
Bambi 
lion 
beast
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! But I think, I simplified my problem to easy, cause that is not solving my problem sorry. The problem is, that this is not working if behind "Animal 1:" is more than just ONE word. For example if the STRING is "Animal 1: rabbit, horse and lion Animal 2: dragon, turtle Animal 3: ..." I want to have
"rabbit, horse and lion", "dragon, turtle", ...

Comment: @BastiTri - I've updated the answer to meet this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!! You are so helpfull! But still somehow I can't addept it to my real problem. 
So I perhaps you can help me again with that: My String is "<w:t>task 1</w:t> XXX <w:t>task 2</w:t> XXX <w:t>task 3</w:t> XXX <w:t>task 4</w:t>" which is an XML String made out of a word document. Now I have to find all the XXX which is written between the <w:t>task n</w:t> and <w:t>task n+1</w:t>

Comment: Ohhh now it worked by changing to  
String[] arr = animals.split("<w:t>task\\s+\\d+</w:t>\\s+");
THANK YOU SO MUCH :) !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern needs to be:

```java
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Animal \\d+:\\s+(\\w+)\\b");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(animals);

while(matcher.find()) { 
     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

that is, word `Animal` followed by a sequence of digits (minimum 1) `\d+` separated with `:` and a sequence of spaces `\\s+` (minimum 1)

The animal name is found as a group #1 `(\w+)\b`, and `\b` means the word boundary.

Thus, the output is:

```java
Rabbit
Horse
Bambi
lion
beast
```

---

Update:

If Java 9+ is used, it is possible to use a stream of match results provided by [`Matcher::results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) instead of `while` loop:

```java
pat.matcher(animals) // apply the pattern to the input string `animals`
   .results()        // get Stream<MatchResult>
   .map(match -> match.group(1))  // convert to Stream<String>
   .forEach(System.out::println); // print each string using method reference
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! But if I understood you right, this works just for "one word", if \b represents a word boundary?
It will not work if my String is for example "Animal 1: rabbit, horse and lion Animal 2: dragon, turtle Animal 3: ..." right? 
Is there a way to show all the words between "Animal 1" and "Animal 2"?

Comment: This works exactly for the case specified in the initial question. The example in the comment has _completely_ different pattern (a set of of words, optionally separated with commas).  Of course, there is a way to resolve this -- for example, shown in the updated answer by @Arvind Kumar Avinash.  As I see, you changed the requirements **again** and I suggest you to get rid of such bad habit.  It also means that your question needs to be more focused.

Comment: Yeah, I realiced, that my simplification was not the right choose and I am sorry for that. But I am new to this kind of programming (with regex) and didn't know, that this would make such a big difference for my real problem (but in fact it did, which I just realiced THEN!). So in the end it's not a "bad habit", but a lack of knowledge by me. Next time, I try to focus my question better, I am sorry, if you feel offended.